# "Socket operation on non-socket" after sending one image with imagezmq

Tags: python, image, sockets, amazon-ec2, pyzmq

I'm trying to implement a server continuously sending jpg images (contained in folder) on a certain port with the Python library imagezmq and then deleting them.
I don't understand why, after sending one image correctly, the server has the error "Socket operation on non-socket". Here's the code:

```
import imagezmq
import os
from time import sleep
import cv2
import subprocess

PORT = 6002
sender_max_res = imagezmq.ImageSender("tcp://*:{}".format(PORT), REQ_REP=False)
print("Creating ImageSender publishing on tcp://*:{}...".format(PORT))
images_dir = "./to_send"

while os.listdir(images_dir):
    try:
        # send image
        print("Files {}".format(os.listdir(images_dir)))
        filename = os.listdir(images_dir)[-1]
        filename_complete = images_dir + "/" + filename
        image = cv2.imread(filename_complete)
        _, image_buffer = cv2.imencode(".JPG", image)
        exif_data_str = "metadata here..."
        sender_max_res.send_jpg(exif_data_str, image_buffer)
        print("Sending file {}".format(filename_complete))
        sleep(5)

        # remove file
        command = "rm " + filename_complete
        print("Executing {}".format(command))
        subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
        sleep(1)

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        sender_max_res.close()
        pass
```

I really don't get why I have this problem, probably is connected to the use of AWS EC2 (ubuntu server). But I don't think it's a problem of port or address, because the first image is sent correctly!
P.s. also the security options are fine, the port 6002 is open.

Comment: Please provide additional information including the line which causes the error and a stack trace

Comment: I don't have more information of this code. The error does not have additional details.
The error comes out executing "sender_max_res.send_jpg(exif_data_str, image_buffer)" the second time!

Comment: Why do you call `sender_max_res.close()` after sending each image? I'm not familiar with imagezmq but my guess is that it closes the underlying connection - thus leading to the error you see. In this case first image would work, more images not - exactly would you experience.

Comment: I can't believe I couldn't see it! Thank you @SteffenUllrich! It's definitely the problem!